# Finding a sub string and deleting it using regex, python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a data set which looks like thus,

```
"See the new #Gucci 5th Ave NY windows customized by @troubleandrew for the debut of the #GucciGhost collection."
"Before the #GucciGhost collection debuts tomorrow, read about the artist @troubleandrew"
```

So i am trying to get rid of all the @ AND the words attached to it. My dataset should look something like this.

```
"See the new #Gucci 5th Ave NY windows customized by for the debut of the #GucciGhost collection."
    "Before the #GucciGhost collection debuts tomorrow, read about the artist"
```

So i can use a simple replace statement to get rid of the `@`. But the adjacent word is a problem.

I am using re to search/find the occurrence. But i am not able to delete this word.

P.S -- If it was a single word, it would have not been a problem. But there are multiple words here and there in my data set attached to `@`

Comment: What is the problem you have? What code does not remove the @+word? Did you try `re.sub`?

Comment: my problem was that i was not able to remove the entire @+word. i was using a   `re.findall`. anyway, `re.sub` works. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex

```
import re

a = [ 
"See the new #Gucci 5th Ave NY windows customized by @troubleandrew for the debut of the #GucciGhost collection.",
"Before the #GucciGhost collection debuts tomorrow, read about the artist @troubleandrew"
]
pat = re.compile(r"@\S+") # \S+ all non-space characters
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = re.sub(pat, "", a[i]) # replace it with empty string
print a
```

This will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatic version, subs extra space:

```
import re

a = [
    "See the new #Gucci 5th Ave NY windows customized by @troubleandrew for the debut of the #GucciGhost collection.",
    "Before the #GucciGhost collection debuts tomorrow, read about the artist @troubleandrew"
]

rgx = re.compile(r"\s?@\S+")

b = [ re.sub(rgx, "", row) for row in a ]

print b
```

`\s?`: `\s` matches `' '` and `?` stands for `zero or one` occurrence.